# OpenCV - Generate adaptive background for video

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I want to achieve something like this-

[Reference Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJVjYB7O9vA)

Say I have a video which is a vertical video(Dimension- 720x1280). I want to create a horizontal video with adaptive background like the video I've shown.
I have written some code for reading and writing to a file.

```
video_index = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videofiles[0])

# video resolution: 1920x1080 px
out = cv2.VideoWriter("video.mp4v",
                      cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'),
                      30, (1920, 1080), 1)
```

What is the effect of having background to the video which smudges on the sides called in opencv/ffmpeg or otherwise?
How do I achieve this effect using code or tools(I am open to using OSS desktop tools)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/43577377

Answer (score 2):

That effect is simply realized by scaling the initial video to the desired size, bluring it, and overlaying the original video on top at the center.

For the blur, I suggest starting with Gaussian blur, available in OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gyan, I used the following piece of code-

```
ffmpeg -i video720x1280.mp4
  -filter_complex
      "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b];
       [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2"   video1920x1080.mp4
```

It worked like charm!

Link to [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579981/3782392).