# Losing video quality during ffmpeg filter_complex

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

My input video is of dimension 720x1280. The output I am getting from the command below is 1920x1080.

The problem that I am facing is, a good 720p video is losing its quality and the output video is deteriorated.

```
ffmpeg -i inter.mpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2" inter_1920x1080.mpg
```

I am ok to scale up my video size to match the 1280 height if downsizing the height is causing the issue. But, is there a way to add custom value to the 'scale'?

Ref:
I have referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43579981/3782392) from Gyan.

---

I tried with the following command now-

```
ffmpeg -i 6691602248444677381.mp4 -c:v -filter_complex "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2" -b:v 800k output.mp4
```

I am getting the following error -

```
[NULL @ 0x7fa2af800000] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2'
[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1: `.mpg` quality is bad

You are using the encoder mpeg1video, the default for `.mpg`, which outputs a very old, legacy format (MPEG-1 Video). The default bitrate value for this ancient encoder is not sufficient for modern sized videos. If this is the format that you want then add the output option `-q:v 3`. Increase the value for less quality. Or choose a bitrate such as `-b:v 8000k` (that's just an arbitrary bitrate value for demonstration purposes).

If MPEG-1 is not the format you want then use the `-c:v` option to choose your desired encoder, and/or change the output container format (such as `.mkv` or `.mp4`).

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i inter.mpg -filter_complex "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2" -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 3 inter_1920x1080.mpg
```

## Question 2: Unable to find a suitable output format for `[0]scale=hd1080...`

You added `-c:v` but did not provide an actual value, so it is assuming your filtergraph is the name of the encoder you want to use. A correct example is `-c:v libx264`.

You are now using `.mp4` so just omit `-c:v` because it will choose a sane default encoder which will be libx264. This encoder outputs H.264 video.

libx264 also has a sane bitrate default, so remove `-b:v 800k`.

Your command should now look like:

```
ffmpeg -i 6691602248444677381.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=hd1080,setsar=1,boxblur=20:20[b]; [0]scale=-1:1080[v];[b][v]overlay=(W-w)/2" output.mp4
```

Comment: You are right. My input is an mp4 file and my output has to be an mp4. I just got a bit deviated seeing some other blog, so maybe my command is incorrect. I have edited my answer to include new command that I'm trying as per your suggestion. Please can you share your thoughts?

Comment: @bozzmob Now that you are using MP4 the situation has changed completely. 1) Remove `-c:v`. This option requires you to provide the name of the encoder you want to use, such as `-c:v libx264`, but you did not provide any value. In this case just let ffmpeg choose the default encoder for MP4 which will be libx264. 2) Remove `-b:v 800k` as the default rate control method for libx264 is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you so much @llogan it worked like charm. Is there a direct way to concatenate mp4's? I usually convert all mp4's to mpg's and concatenate them and reconvert the final mpg to mp4 again.

I tried doing - `cat output1.mp4 output2.mp4 > final.mp4`. But, `final.mp4` only contains the first video for some reason. What is the most efficient way to concatenate them?

Comment: @bozzmob Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1). Also see [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer), and there are many questions here on SO asking how to use it. You can search SO with `[ffmpeg] is:answer concat demuxer`.